# C++ pcap_loop() arguments issue

Tags: c++, pcap

I am trying to pass NULL into pcap_loop() functions just as the [tcpdump man](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

This is my callback function that I want to trigger:

```
void Home::gotPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
                const u_char *packet){

}
```

Firstly I tried this:

```
pcap_loop(handle, 0, gotPacket, NULL);
```

Secondly I tried passing a variable with NULL value instead:

```
u_char *arg = NULL;
pcap_loop(handle, 0, gotPacket, arg);
```

Both the first and second methods returned this error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
pcap_loop(handle, 0, gotPacket, NULL);
                                    ^

error: invalid use of non-static member function
pcap_loop(handle, 0, gotPacket, arg);
                                   ^
```

How can I solve that error? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure the problem is that `Home::gotPacket` is not `static`. Consider changing it to `static` like that:

```
static void Home::gotPacket(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
                const u_char *packet){

}
```

This should solve your problem